# awk if expression creates 0 and 1 instead of expected result

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk, split

The input file is tab separated and looks like this:

```
]2      71319482        71319483        71319483        MantaBND
8       17715051        17715052        17715052        MantaDEL
]5      137014789       137014790       137014790       MantaBND
8       34426251        34426252        34426252        MantaDEL
C]14    36674759        36674760        36674760        MantaBND
```

I used the following awk command ..

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t"} {if ($1 = /^].*/) {{split ($1,a,/]/);$10=a[1]}; {print $10, $2, $3, $4, $5"HT"}} else {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}}' file
```

..to generate a result that should look like this:

```
2      71319482        71319483        71319483        MantaBNDHT
8       17715051        17715052        17715052        MantaDEL
5      137014789       137014790       137014790       MantaBNDHT
8       34426251        34426252        34426252        MantaDEL
C]14    36674759        36674760        36674760        MantaBND
```

But instead the result looks like this:

```
1       71319482        71319483        71319483        MantaBNDHT
0       17715051        17715052        17715052        MantaDEL
1       137014789       137014790       137014790       MantaBNDHT
0       34426251        34426252        34426252        MantaDEL
0       36674759        36674760        36674760        MantaBND
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve the problem? I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Column 1 is wrong because you use `=` in your `if` statement instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

using sub instead of split would be possible too, but using only sub leads to a mistake in column 5, so I finally found a way (thanks to oliv, = and == lead to a wrong result, so I tested ~.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t"} {if ($1 ~ /^].*/) {{split ($1,a,/]/);$10=a[2]}; {print $10, $2, $3, $4, $5"HT"}} else {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}}' file

2       71319482        71319483        71319483        MantaBNDHT
8       17715051        17715052        17715052        MantaDEL
5       137014789       137014790       137014790       MantaBNDHT
8       34426251        34426252        34426252        MantaDEL
C]14    36674759        36674760        36674760        MantaBND
```